# Python parallel execution with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I'm confused about parallel execution in python using selenium. There seems to be a few ways to go about it, but some seem out of date.

1. There's a python module called `python-wd-parallel` which seems to have some functionality to do this, but it's from 2013, is this still useful now? I also found [this example](https://saucelabs.com/blog/parallel-testing-with-python-and-selenium-on-sauce-online-workshop-recap).
2. There's `concurrent.futures`, this seems a lot newer, but not so easy to implement. *Anyone have a working example with parallel execution in selenium?*
3. There's also using just threads and executors to get the job done, but I feel this will be slower, because it's not using all the cores and is still running in serial formation.

What is the *latest way* to do parallel execution using selenium?

Comment: About the item 1. There are many of companies out there that offer solutions for paralalel testing. Saucelabs is one of those. But there are many more listed [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/getting_started/) on selenium grid page. Selenium grid is also an alternative for not pure python parallelism.

Comment: Just to complete those companies are listed as *Selenium Level Sponsors*.

Answer (score 12):

Use [joblib's Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html) module to do that, its a great library for parallel execution.

Lets say we have a list of urls named `urls` and we want to take a screenshot of each one in parallel

First lets import the necessary libraries

```
from selenium import webdriver
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

Now lets define a function that takes a screenshot as base64

```
def take_screenshot(url):
    phantom = webdriver.PhantomJS('/path/to/phantomjs')
    phantom.get(url)
    screenshot = phantom.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    phantom.close()

    return screenshot
```

Now to execute that in parallel what you would do is

```
screenshots = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(take_screenshot)(url) for url in urls)
```

When this line will finish executing, you will have in `screenshots` all of the data from all of the processes that ran.

**Explanation about Parallel**

- `Parallel(n_jobs=-1)` means use all of the resources you can
- `delayed(function)(input)` is `joblib`'s way of creating the input for the function you are trying to run on parallel

More information can be found on the `joblib` docs

Comment: Is there any straight-forward way to re-use one webdriver.PhantomJS instance for one n_jobs, rather than closing and opening for every iteration?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It seems like a bad idea to try to access one webdriver instance from multiple processes - I believe that will hurt parallelization. Anyway if you decide to go on with that, you will have to make the webdriver serializeable

Comment: many thanks. my rational was to have one driver instance for each process (not one driver instance for more than one process) since in the list "how to speed up selenium" the line item "reuse driver instances" is pretty much on top

Comment: You are right, in the code that what is happens. `take_screenshot` is basically what happens on every process, you can do what you want in that function. So you basically create a webdriver instance for each process, do what you will in that process and close it before the process is done

Comment: To not recreate instances, I would chop the `urls` list to even sized sublists, and then send them to the processes, that way the spawning of the processes (and the creation of the webdriver instance) will happen only once per process

Comment: thanks for your advise - that's exactly what I wanted to know - do you think that this approach has any potential in significantly speeding up scraping large URL pools (educated guess)? I am new to selenium and am glad for every input at this stage

Comment: As I see it it depends. It is all a function of the overhead of spawning processes and transferring data between them against the benefits of parallelization - But mostly, if the operations are not really short, you would benefit from using a parallel implementation

Answer (score 8):

1. **[Python Parallel Wd](https://github.com/OniOni/python-parallel-wd)** seams to be dead from its github (last commit 9 years ago). Also it implements an [obsolete protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) for selenium. Finally code is proprietary [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/).

*Generally it's better to use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)* a Python test framework based on selenium and pytest. It's very complete and supports everything for a performance boost, parallel threads and so much more. ***If that's not your case ... keep reading.***

### Selenium Performance Boost ([concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html))

#### Short Answer

- **Both `threads` and `processes` will give you a *considerable speed up* on your *selenium code*.**

Short examples are given bellow. The selenium work is done by `selenium_title` function that return the page title. That don't deal with exceptions happening during each thread/process execution. For that look *Long Answer* - *Dealing with exceptions*.

1. Pool of thread workers [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from concurrent import futures

def selenium_title(url):  
  wdriver = webdriver.Chrome() # chrome webdriver
  wdriver.get(url)  
  title = wdriver.title  
  wdriver.quit()
  return title

links = ["https://www.amazon.com", "https://www.google.com"]

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: # default/optimized number of threads
  titles = list(executor.map(selenium_title, links))
```

2. Pool of processes workers  [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor). Just need to replace `ThreadPoolExecuter` by `ProcessPoolExecutor` in the code above. They are both derived from the `Executor` base class. Also you **must** protect the *main*, like below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: # default/optimized number of processes
   titles = list(executor.map(selenium_title, links))
```

#### Long Answer

##### Why `Threads` with Python GIL works?

Even tough Python has limitations on threads due the Python GIL and even though threads will be context switched. Performance gain will come due to implementation details of Selenium. Selenium works by sending commands like `POST`, `GET` (`HTTP requests`). Those are sent to the browser driver server. Consequently you might already know I/O bound tasks (`HTTP requests`) releases the GIL, so the performance gain.

##### Dealing with exceptions

We can make small modifications on the example above to deal with `Exceptions` on the threads spawned. Instead of using `executor.map` we use `executor.submit`. That will return the title wrapped on `Future` instances.

To access the returned title we can use `future_titles[index].result` where index size `len(links)`, or simple use a `for` like bellow.

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  future_titles = [ executor.submit(selenium_title, link) for link in links ]
  for future_title, link in zip(future_titles, links): 
    try:        
      title = future_title.result() # can use `timeout` to wait max seconds for each thread               
    except Exception as exc: # this thread migh have had an exception
      print('url {:0} generated an exception: {:1}'.format(link, exc))
```

Note that besides iterating over `future_titles` we iterate over `links` so in case an `Exception` in some thread  we know which `url(link)` was responsible for that.

The `futures.Future` class are cool because they give you control on the results received from each thread. Like if it completed correctly or there was an exception and others, more about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects).

Also important to mention is that [`futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) is better if you don´t care which order the threads return items. But since the syntax to control exceptions with that is a little ugly I omitted it here.

##### Performance gain and Threads

First why I've been always using threads for speeding up my selenium code:

- On I/O bound tasks my experience with selenium shows that there's [minimal or no diference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997963/1207193) between using a pool of Processes (`Process`) or Threads (`Threads`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55319297/1207193) also reach similar conclusions about Python threads vs processes on I/O bound tasks.
- We also know that processes use their own memory space. That means more memory consumption. Also processes are a little slower to be spawned than threads.